MESHブロックの定時通信が止まる
SONY MESH-100AC 動きセンサーに関する質問です。
・環境：Raspberry Pi 5
・開発言語：Python 3.11.2
公開されているPythonプログラムをベースにアプリを作成しています。
MESH-100AC から送信される「定時通信」ですが、15回ほど受信した後、
通信が途絶えてしまいます。（再現性アリ）
通信が途絶えた後、MESH-100AC を操作しても、傾き検知できません。

プログラムが停止しているということはありません。
プログラムを再起動すると、また。定時通信を受信します。
定時通信受信中は、傾き検知を受信しますが、定時通信を15回ほど受信したのち、
受信がされなくなります。
作成したプログラムですが、これまで（１週間ほど前まで）は定時通信が停止することはなく、プログラムを停止するまで、定時通信を受信し続けていました。

何か原因は考えられますでしょうか？よろしくお願いいたします。
以下にコネクション直後のレシーブデータを記します。
2024-05-28 09:37:10,020 - [wait_MESH] found : MESH-100AC1022446 DC:87:86:B8:8D:CA
2024-05-28 09:37:12,935 - [indicate]
2024-05-28 09:37:13,081 - [indicate]
2024-05-28 09:37:13,081 - [wait_MESH] connected
2024-05-28 09:37:13,178 - [wait_MESH] Received data: 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03
2024-05-28 09:37:13,179 - [wait_MESH] Received data: 00 02 01 ee 99 0f 00 01 02 05 01 07 49 00 0a fc
2024-05-28 09:37:13,180 - [wait_MESH] Received data: 00 06 c8 00 f0 00 01 00 90 01 c0 a8 00 00 b8
2024-05-28 09:37:50,326 - [wait_MESH] Received data: 00 00 0a 0a
2024-05-28 09:37:50,327 - [定時通信] バッテリーレベル：10
2024-05-28 09:38:47,364 - [wait_MESH] Received data: 00 00 0a 0a
2024-05-28 09:38:47,365 - [定時通信] バッテリーレベル：10

